# IIS request failed after 15 minutes

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, iis, timeout

I am encountering a problem with request done to a WCF application hosted in IIS 8.5. The problem is that request fails after exactly 15 minutes (every time), but the thread continues to work behind the scenes (finishes the invoked action after 15 minutes).

The test we have done a through a web application that connects to WCF service and also using the WcfTestClient.exe, the result is the same.

We have checked all the configurations in IIS and nothing points to 15 minutes timeout. Service binding has more than 15 minutes for receiveTimeout and sendTimeout.

Has anyone encounter this problem? We can't find the cause of this behavior.

Thank you

Comment: try changing the idle Time-out of the website pool (under application pool - the default is 20 m)
change it to 30 minutes and see if this solves the problem

Comment: the idle timeout was set to 0 so it was not the cause of this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end it was a configuration on a proxy server that was in front of the IIS server. It had a timeout setting of 15 minutes.

Comment: How do you fix it? what you mean?

Comment: It was a configuration on a different server sitting in front of the IIS server. It had nothing to do with IIS.